# how to remove AM/PM from bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker is there a function to remove am/pm or is there any other way of doing it?

PS there is similar post but it is different this is for datetimepicker not for time picker

Answer (score 1):

Use 12 `Hrs` format

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'HH:mm'});
```

Comment: I've tried this also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The second example on https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ already :

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    pick12HourFormat: false
});
```

Comment: doesn't work still shows